# Finding the recurrence equations of a function

Tags: recurrence

I have to find the recurrence equations of the following function:

```
static int f(int[] a, int inf, int sup) {
    if(sup == inf) 
        return a[inf];
    if(sup == inf+1) 
        return a[inf] + a[sup];
    else {
        int thrd = (sup - inf + 1)/3;
        int i = inf + thrd;
        int j = i + thrd;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k = i; k < j; k++) 
            sum += a[k]; 
        return f(a, inf, i-1) + f(a, j, sup) + sum;
    }
}
```

The base case is **T(1) = 1** (from `if(sup == inf)` to `sum += a[k];`).
Instead the recursive case what is? I would say **T(n) = 2T(n/3) + 1** but I'm not sure..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the cost for each line of your recursive case

```
static int f(int[] a, int inf, int sup) {
  if(sup == inf) 
    return a[inf];
  if(sup == inf+1) 
    return a[inf] + a[sup];
  else {
    int thrd = (sup - inf + 1)/3;                  //O(1)
    int i = inf + thrd;                            //O(1)
    int j = i + thrd;                              //O(1)
    int sum = 0;                                   //O(1)
    for(int k = i; k < j; k++) sum += a[k];        //O(n/3)
    return f(a, inf, i-1) + f(a, j, sup) + sum;    //2 * T(n/3)
  }
}
```

The O(n/3) comes from the fact that your for loop is iterating over one third of your input size, and the 2 * T(n/3) term comes from the fact that we are recursing on one third of the input size twice.  This gives us

```
T(n) = O(1) + O(1) + O(1) + O(1) + O(n/3) + 2 * T(n/3)
```

Since O(1) + O(1) is still O(1), the first 4 O(1)'s collapse into a single term, and O(n/3) is the same as O(n), we are left with

```
T(n) = 2T(n/3) + O(n) + O(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution of T(n), what is? I have thought about this one: **2T(n/3) + sum from i=0 to i=(k-1) of (2^i) + sum from i=1 to i=(k-1) of [((2^i) * n)/3^i]** but it's not the solution..